# most efficient way to print a list of names based off a csv using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, performance

I have an array of player's IDs. There will generally be about 5 players, not likely to be more then a dozen:

```
$cplayers= array(1,2,5);
```

I want to display the players names as a list.

```
$query = "SELECT username,id FROM users ORDER BY id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$playercounter =0;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {

  if ($row['id'] == $cplayers[$playercounter]) {
    echo "<li>".$row['username']."</li>";
    $playercounter++;
    }
  }
```

So I'm pretty sure this isn't the most efficient way I could do this. Would it be better to do individual queries? 
Also is there a good way to exit the while loop once `$cplayers` is done?

Comment: Do you need to call `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` twice in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apparently the answer is rather to normalize my database, have a separate (third) table for the join of the two rather than using an array w/in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

just change your query to this:

```
$query = "SELECT username,id FROM users WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$cplayers).")ORDER BY id";
```

this will return the correct players you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I'm interpreting this, I'd use the MySQL IN clause, e.g.

```
$id_list= array(1,2,5);
$sql= 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE id IN('. join(",",$id_list) .') ORDER BY id';
$result= mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
while($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<li>{$row['username']}</li>";
}
```

This targets only those id values in the list, is that what you want?